# I want to hide a div when one input is in focus in Angular 4 or Angular 6

Tags: angular

I want to hide a div when an input is in focus.

I tried to hide another div by ng-class however I really don't know how to implement it.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-9">
 <input id="notes" placeholder="Notes" formControlName="notes" />
  <div id="another-div">Test div which is hidden when notes input is in focus
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you can do this with css<sup>1</sup> only:

```css
input:focus+div{ display:none; }
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-9">
  <input id="notes" placeholder="Notes" formControlName="notes" />
  <div id="another-div">Test div which is hidden when notes input is in focus
  </div>
</div>
```

<sup>Note: 1. This requires a div after the input.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-9">
    <input id="notes" placeholder="Notes" formControlName="notes" (focus)="isDivHidden = true" (blur)="isDivHidden = false"/>
    <div id="another-div" *ngIf="!isDivHidden">Test div which is hidden when notes input is in focus
    </div>
</div>
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v5n5ou?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Answer (score 1):

You can check if input is touched.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-9">
 <input id="notes" placeholder="Notes" formControlName="notes" />
  <div *ngIf="!(notes.dirty || notes.touched)" id="another-div">Test div which is hidden when notes input is in focus
 </div>
</div>
```